# Ubuntu installation does not respond after rebooting

Tags: installation, 12.10, reboot

I installed Ubuntu and after completing the steps at the website and rebooting my computer shows a menu to choose between Ubuntu and windows 7.

When I choose Ubuntu it shows that it is completing installation and a dialogue box appears which shows the status of "copying files..." and then after a few seconds it shows "almost finished copying files" and it remains like that. After this it does not shows any increment in the process so I assume that it is hanged.

Please help. I already tried opening my windows 7 and it opened just fine. I need to complete my installation today because i need some important data from my external hard disk which is not accessible in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the important data you can always run your live cd and access the external hd. Copy whatever you need to your windows partition and work there or etc etc etc

My recommendation is to try to reinstall ubuntu altogether, it doesn't seem like you had a previous installation of it anyway.